# Can google firebase trigger receive google pub/sub message only once at the time

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, message-queue, google-cloud-pubsub

I currently working on a sync third party data project, that I decided to implement queue to ensure the message has received to the worker, but the worker need to do only one task at the time, which means the previous task should finished and acknowledged before executing the next one.

so the question is, how can I config the firebase pub/sub trigger to execute task one by one ?.
If I misunderstand on the concept of google pub/sub feel free to tell me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do isn't really compatible with the way pubsub functions work.  There are other Google Cloud products that can help you limit the rate of invocation of some code, but it won't be implemented with a pubsub type function.

GCP offers a product called [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/), which lets you set up a [queue](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-queues) that can be [configured with a rate limit](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-queues#rate).  The queue can dispatch a task invocation to [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-appengine-tasks), or to an [HTTP type Cloud Function (beta).](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks)  So, if you've deployed an HTTP function, you could use its endpoint URL to configure a Cloud Tasks queue that invokes that function only once at a time.

Comment: Oh that should be what I looking for !! :D. just another one question, I see Pub/sub supported pull message mechanism so what is different between to use cloud task and Google pub/sub with pull mechanism ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Perhaps you would like to post a whole new question and go into more detail, with links to documentation, about explaining what is unclear to you?

Answer (score 0):

You can control the number of instances of Cloud Functions with the `MAX-INSTANCES` flag of `gcloud` command line tool. See the documentation on [Using max instances](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/max-instances) for full details.

The Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions doesn't wrap this option (yet). But you can deploy the function using the Firebase CLI, and then change the setting in the Cloud console, by following the steps shown in [Clearing max instances limits](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/max-instances#clearing_max_instances_limits).

Comment: The max instances configuration does NOT fully force the number of instances.  There are circumstances where the limit will be exceeded.  For example [handling traffic spikes](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/max-instances#handling_traffic_spikes) and [during deployment](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/max-instances#deployments).  For these reasons, I would not recommend using this configuration to force a serialization of function execution - there is simply no guarantee that it will work as expected.